# Remove a single style from <style> inside <head> jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I want to remove a single style eg:

```
img{width:calc(100% - 10px)}
```

From my `<style>` which is inserted dynamically by a plugin inside `<head>`. I tried many ways but nothing help.

```
ThElement.find('style').remove();
```

By using the above code I could remove all the `<style>` together, But I need to remove the only single style. So Is there any way to do it.

**I don't want to add a new style, I just want to remove existing**

Here is a fiddle for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html {
      margin: 0px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    body {
      height: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      background: transparent;
      color: #000000;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      -webkit-user-select: auto;
      margin: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      min-height: 20px;
    }
    
    body:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    body::-moz-selection {
      background: #b5d6fd;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    body::selection {
      background: #b5d6fd;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    body,
    textarea {
      min-height: 500px !important;
    }
    
    body,
    body:focus {
      outline: transparent solid 0px;
    }
    
    body {
      background: transparent;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      overflow-x: auto;
      user-select: auto;
    }
    
    body a {
      user-select: auto;
    }
    
    body table td,
    body table th {
      border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    }
    
    body table td:empty,
    body table th:empty {
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    body table td,
    body table th {
      border: 1px double red;
    }
    
    body table td,
    body table th {
      border-width: 2px;
    }
    
    body table th {
      background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    }
    
    body hr {
      clear: both;
      user-select: none;
      break-after: page;
    }
    
    body img {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    body ::after {
      position: relative;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    body pre {
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    
    body blockquote {
      border-left: 2px solid rgb(94, 53, 177);
      margin-left: 0px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      color: rgb(94, 53, 177);
    }
    
    body blockquote blockquote {
      border-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
      color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    }
    
    body blockquote blockquote blockquote {
      border-color: rgb(67, 160, 71);
      color: rgb(67, 160, 71);
    }
    
    body span {
      font-weight: normal;
      display: inline;
      line-height: 0;
    }
    
    body span {
      font-size: inherit;
      height: 1em;
      width: 1em;
      min-height: 20px;
      min-width: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: -0.2em 0.15em 0.2em;
      line-height: normal;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/">
</body>

</html>
```

I just want to remove the `body img` style from it.

Comment: Can you give some example of your styles ? I want to see content under <style>

Comment: Let me create a fiddle for you guys.

Comment: Instead of removing it by editing the DOM, you can select the element and unset the style on it.

Comment: I have added a fiddle for you guys. @SandeshGupta the element is dynamic it can be created more or maybe none. so I don't know how exactly your solution work. If it I will be happy to use it.

Comment: Example you given has multiple style for body. So, in that case how do you want to remove ? How do you will select a css under a style ? By index or by name ?

Comment: @MAKRipon *I just want to remove the 'body img' style from it.* it's the style for `image` inside the `body` not the style of the `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit funky-looking but you can remove the particular rule using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Something like this:

```
var style = $('head>style');
style.text( style.text().replace(/(img\s*\{[^}]*)max-width:\s*calc\(100%\s*-\s*10px\);([^}]*\})/g, "$1$2") );
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/KarlosSultana/dwqryvcf/)

Or, to remove all img styles is a bit simpler:

```
var style = $('head>style');
style.text( style.text().replace(/img\s*\{[^}]*\}/g, "img {}") );
```

[Another JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KarlosSultana/dwqryvcf/10/)

If you need to remove a more specific selector then you can modify the `regex`:

```
var style = $('head>style');
style.text( style.text().replace(/body\simg\.fr-dii\s*\{[^}]*\}/g, "") );
```

[One more JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KarlosSultana/dwqryvcf/13/)

Comment: This worked for me but can you help me remove all the style of the `img` tag.?

Comment: Sure, I've just edited the answer to show this, with another JSFiddle

Comment: my actual style is `body img.fr-dii`, your solution only removes the `max-width` for me, I don't know why. second one also same result.!

Comment: OK, have added this to answer as well

Answer (score -1):

you can override head style

1. new  tag
2. img onload callback - set css width custom size

:)

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow** please read the question carefully and answer it with your own ideas and code sample and for a better answer, you should also explain you answer well.